# Passing variables from Servlet to JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I know this is an old question and many people asked, but I can't really get mine work (i.e., `${uname}` is always empty)...

My tomcat webapp is like:

`member.jsp`:

(The laster half of this jsp is to confirm the content of cookies)

```
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${cookie.containsKey('uname')}">
            <h1>Super Secure Shopping Mall</h1>
            <p>Hello, ${uname}!</p>
            <p><a href="Logout">Logout</a></p>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <p>Please login first!</p>
            <p><a href="main.jsp">Login</a></p>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    <%
    Cookie cookie_debug = null;
    Cookie[] cookies_debug = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies_debug != null) {
        out.println("<h2>DEBUG: Cookies</h2>");
        for (int i=0;i<cookies_debug.length;i++) {
            cookie_debug = cookies_debug[i];
            out.println("Cookie No." + String.valueOf(i) + ": " + cookie_debug.getName() + ", " + cookie_debug.getValue() + "<br/>");
        }
    }
    else {
        out.println("<p>No cookie found.</p>");
    }
    %>
```

`member.java`:

```
import java.io.*;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.sql.*;

// @WebServlet("/member")
public class Member extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Member() {super();}

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Cookie[] cks = request.getCookies();
        Cookie ck = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < cks.length; i++) {
            ck = cks[i];
            if (ck.getName().equals("uname")) {
                request.setAttribute("uname", ck.getValue());
                break;
            }
        }

        // dispatch requests
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/member.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    }
}
```

Project Folder Structure:

```
Webapp
 |- member.jsp
 |- WEB-INF
    |- classes
       |- Member.java
```

I know that I can get the cookie value in other ways, but I want to know why isn't this working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The problem is that I need to reach this webpage by `member`, instead of `member.jsp`.